# Swipe 2 views postions in autolayout during run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I'm looking for customized solution.
I have these two buttons with their constrains

[image: Confirm Button]
[image: Cancel Button]

I want to swipe their places During run time.

I've tried the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` option but it's misbehave in many scenarios.
also I can't just outlet some constrains and change their constants during run time because the two buttons are related to each other

What to do ?

Comment: are you looking for some animation or you want their position to be interchanged?

Comment: just their position to be interchanged

Answer (score 1):

If you just want position of both button to change and not to perform any animation, then you can simply swap the background color and title text of next/back buttons. You would also need some extra logic to handle actions of both buttons after the swap.

In that way they will appear swapped

Comment: although this is not an actual answer to my question but this work around is great thank you bro so much !